# Is it possible to invert an arbitrary lambda in Python?

Tags: python, math, lambda

I have been playing around with Python and math lately, and I ran in to something I have yet to be able to figure out. Namely, is it possible, given an arbitrary lambda, to return the inverse of that lambda for mathematical operations? That is, invertLambda such that invertLambda(lambda x:(x+2))(2) = 0. The fact that lambdas are restricted to expressions gives me hope, but so far I have not been able to make it work. I understand that any result would have problems with functions that lose information, but I am willing to restrict users and myself to lossless functions if I have to.

Comment: They are restricted to expressions, but expressions can have arbitrary functions in them!

Comment: You'd be getting into murky realms of byte-code dodgery to make it work, at best.

Comment: Have you looked at [SymPy](http://code.google.com/p/sympy/)?  I'd bet that might be a better fit for the problem it sounds like you're trying to solve.

Comment: @KellerScholl: you should not be using lambdas if you seek to invert them. You should be building your functions in a declarative domain-specific language (e.g. as Class-based combinators), compiling them into lambdas, or inverting them in the DSL, and compiling the inverted function into lambdas. By "compile" I mean for example your `Expression` class might have a `.eval({x:1, y=2})` function. e.g. `Line(a=1, b=2).invert().eval({x:0})` -> `2`. Python is absolutely terrible at symbolic manipulation because it is so eagerly evaluated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course not: if lambda is not an [injective function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function), you cannot invert it. Example: you cannot invert lambda mapping `x` to `x*x`, since the sign of the original `x` is lost.

Leaving injectivity aside, there are functions which are computationally very complex to invert. Consider, for example, restoring the original value from its md5 hash. (For a lambda calculating md5 hash, inverted function must break md5 in cryptological sense!)

---

Edit:
indeed, we can theoretically make lambdas invertable if we restrict the expressions which can be used there. For example, if the lambda is a linear function of 1 argument, we can easily invert it. If it's a polynomial of degree > 4, we have a problem with algebraically exact solution.

Of course, we could refrain from *exact* solution, and just invert the function *numerically*. This is possible, using, well, any method of [numerical solving](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm) of the equation `lambda(x) = value` will do (the simplest be binary search).

Comment: Edited in response. Thank you.

Comment: @Keller: well, do we want to prohibit function calls in the considered lambdas, too? Otherwise the lambda could just call md5 hash calculation.

Comment: @Lev: of course not -- but we restrict us now to the problem of finding _any_ value that the original lambda would map to the given value.

Comment: So, given a lambda that is theoretically invertable, is it possible in Python to invert it exactly?

Comment: @Keller: Well, with introspection perhaps you can see the expression which makes up the lambda. (I'm not a Python expert, but in some other languages this would be possible.) If you would restrict the content of the lambda, this could be even easier. For example: if lambda is known to be a linear function, you can calculate its parameters by knowing its value at 2 distinct points (say, 0 and 1).

Comment: @Keller: ... If the lambda maps x to kx + b, than b = f(0) and k = f(1) - b, so the inverse function would be x -> (1/k)x - b/k. For more complex function set, you would need more complicated logic.

Comment: @Keller: If it's a simple mathematical statement, sure - you learn the algorithm for inverting a function in high-school *(though, I'm not sure if it's possible to do it with lambdas in Pythons - you'd need access to the expression tree)*.  Once you start adding loops and conditionals and turing-completeness, though, you're almost certainly venturing into the realm of [undecidable problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem).

Comment: @Keller: theoretically, _any_ injective function is invertable. But really inverting it might be complicated. Example: x->sin(x*x) is invertable in some neighbourhood of 0, but you cannot invert it analytically.

Comment: @Danny Pflughoeft I know how to invert a given mathematical function. Can I access this expression tree for a lambda?

Comment: @Keller: at least you can use [dis](http://docs.python.org/library/dis.html) to get the bytecode.

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit late, but I just published a python package that does this precisely. You may want to borrow some ideas from it:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pynverse

It essentially follows this strategy:

1. Figure out if the function is increasing or decreasing. For this two reference points ref1 and ref2 are needed:

   - In case of a finite interval, the points ref points are 1/4 and 3/4 through the interval.
   - In an infinite interval any two values work really.
   - If f(ref1) < f(ref2), the function is increasing, otherwise is decreasing.
2. Figure out the image of the function in the interval.

   - If values are provided, then those are used.
   - In a closed interval just calculate f(a) and f(b), where a and b are the ends of the interval.
   - In an open interval try to calculate f(a) and f(b), if this works those are used, otherwise it will be assume to be (-Inf, Inf).
3. Built a bounded function with the following conditions:

   - bounded_f(x):

     - return -Inf if x below interval, and f is increasing.
     - return +Inf if x below interval, and f is decreasing.
     - return +Inf if x above interval, and f is increasing.
     - return -Inf if x above interval, and f is decreasing.
     - return f(x) otherwise
4. If the required number y0 for the inverse is outside the image, raise an exception.
5. Find roots for bounded_f(x)-y0, by minimizing (bounded_f(x)-y0)**2, using the `Brent` method, making sure that the algorithm for minimising starts in a point inside the original interval by setting ref1, ref2 as brackets. As soon as if goes outside the allowed intervals, bounded_f returns infinite, forcing the algorithm to go back to search inside the interval.
6. Check that the solutions are accurate and they meet f(x0)=y0 to some desired precision, raising a warning otherwise.

Of course, as Vlad pointed out, the function has to be invertible for the inverse to exist, and also continuous in the domain for this to work.